# dateDiff mongoDb rounding off the difference

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

My aggregate query

```
'$dateDiff': 
    { 
        'startDate': '$updatedAt', 
        'endDate': new Date(), 
        'unit': "hour" 
    }
```

Example: My updatedAt is 10:00 (2023-06-08T10:00:00.502+00:00)
and my now is 1:50 (2023-06-08T13:54:00.502+00:00 )

My expected dateDiff is 3 but this is returning me 4.
Its rounding off but I want it to floor. How to achieve this ?

Comment: Can you please give precise input values. Input values `10:00` and `1:50` are not useful when you complain about wrong result.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit 2023-06-08T10:00:00.502+00:00 and 2023-06-08T13:54:00.502+00:00 these are my exact values. I want dateDiff to floor the values instead of roundOff

Comment: There must be something wrong with your data. Result is 3 as you expect: https://mongoplayground.net/p/c6DzV85hs2T

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit My date is correct. If I take the value and try it in mongoPlayground it's working fine. But in the whole aggregation is not working. The only difference is my time is in UTC and I am not converting it to ISODate.

Comment: `Date` values in MongoDB are **always** stored as UTC time. Do you store the date values as string? You should **never** do that, it's a design flaw. And your question is just another proof for that statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      dateDiff: {
        // floor the result of division
        $floor: {
          // divide the difference of dates by 1000 * 60 * 60 to get the difference in hours
          $divide: [
            {
              // subtract the dates to get the difference in milliseconds
              $subtract: [new Date(), '$updatedAt'],
            },
            1000 * 60 * 60,
          ],
        },
      },
    },
  },
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below as template

```
db.collection.aggregate([   {
    $match: {
      updatedAt: {
        $date: {
          $year: 2023,
          $month: 6,
          $day: 8,
          $hour: 10,
        },
      },
    },   },   {
    $dateDiff: {
      startDate: '$updatedAt',
      endDate: new Date(),
      unit: "hour",
    },   },   {
    $floor: {
      $dateDiff: {
        startDate: '$updatedAt',
        endDate: new Date(),
        unit: "hour",
      },
    },   }, ]);
```

will return the number of hours between the `updatedAt` field and the current time. The `$floor operator` will then round down the result to the nearest integer.

The reason why your original query was returning 4 is because the `$dateDiff operator` rounds up the result. This is because the `$dateDiff operator uses the IEEE 754 double-precision floating-point format` to represent numbers. This format has a limited number of digits after the decimal point, so rounding up is necessary to ensure that the result is accurate.

The `$floor operator`, on the other hand, does not round up. It simply rounds down the result to the nearest integer. This is why the `$floor operator w`ill return 3 in this case.
`$dateDiff pipeline stage` is not supported in `MongoDB 4.0`. It was introduced in `MongoDB 4.2.`